# generating new column with time delta within other columns in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, time-series

I have a data frame looking like this:

```
    0         1       2       .... 200  
   12:30:45   78      78            89
   12:38:50   98      98            99
   12:44:55   178    178            189
```

Here column:0 contains timestamps and column 1:200 contain values. I want to create a new column: 'difference' that will take time difference between that row and previous row. the value in first row can be 0. So my resulting dataframe should look like:

```
     0         1       2       .... 200     difference
   12:30:45   78      78            89        0
   12:30:51   98      98            99        6
   12:30:55   178    178            189       4
```

Comment: do you want the difference in seconds? note that column:0 in the DataFrame above is different from column:0 in the DataFrame below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could convert column 0 to `datetime`, then use `shift` + `sub` to get the differences:

```
df[0] = pd.to_datetime(df[0])
df['difference'] = df[0].sub(df[0].shift(fill_value=df.at[0,0])).dt.total_seconds()
```

Output:

```
                    0    1    2  200  difference
0 2022-03-31 12:30:45   78   78   89         0.0
1 2022-03-31 12:38:50   98   98   99       485.0
2 2022-03-31 12:44:55  178  178  189       365.0
```

Comment: it gives me a 'KeyError: 0'

Comment: @KathanVyas aren’t the column names integers? Could post the output of `print(df.head().to_dict())` ?

Comment: I changed the name of the column to 'Time' to avoid that and replaced individually the corresponding zeros with 'Time' and I am still getting error @enke

Comment: here is the output to what you asked:

{'Time': {232: Timestamp('2018-02-13 00:35:00.067000'), 233: Timestamp('2018-02-13 00:35:01.071000'), 234: Timestamp('2018-02-13 00:35:02.075000'), 235: Timestamp('2018-02-13 00:35:03.067000'), 236: Timestamp('2018-02-13 00:35:04.023000')}, 1: {232: 2033, 233: 2033, 234: 2032, 235: 2034, 236: 2032}, 2: {232: 2032, 233: 2033, 234: 2032, 235: 2034, 236: 2032}, 3: {232: 2032, 233:

Comment: nevermind. I figured it. it was my mistake